# Jira import Issues via CSV. Comments missing

Tags: csv, import, comments, jira

I've got a CSV ready to import in to Jira via the Issues CSV importer wizard. Apparently you can import comments too. So I have followed their instructions per the documentation, and each comment has its own column in the CSV.

I should be seeing a "Comment Body" mapping value when Jira asks me to map my columns to Jira fields. I do not see this.

Does anyone know how I import comments with my issues as a CSV? I've looked everywhere and I just cannot get that field to display in mappings.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Atlassian answers this issue by explaining the user should utilis "[Import from external system](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/9866203/cant-seem-to-map-csv-into-key-jira-fieldsstatus-assignee-etc)" feature to import comments.

Also, in the current web-based UI, use the following steps to access the importer that allows mapping of comment fields:

1. Click on the gear menu button in the upper-right corner of the
   screen
2. Click on the "System" choice
3. In the resulting left-hand menu pane click "External System Import"
4. Choose the CSV selection from the gird of choices presented in the
   resulting right-hand pane.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer for this now.

If you expand "Issues" in the top menu and find "Import from CSV" then you'll run in to the same problem I did.

When on this page click "Back" and then from the list of import plugins choose "CSV". (because that's not confusing) you'll get an entirely different CSV import wizard which will include a much more comprehensive list of columns and import options.

For a decent product its a shame the user experience is a bit sketchy sometimes.

Comment: Another way to access is "Configure" => "System" => "External System Import" => "CSV"